# Vue.js Multiple API Call with relation

Tags: vue.js, object, nuxt.js

I have this structure folder:

```
components/
  character.vue
```

```
pages/
  teams/
    _id.vue
```

In the `_id.vue` file I have a `mounted` function to get the team with a specific ID:

```js
data () {
  return{
    id: this.$route.params.id,
    team: [],
  }
},
mounted () {
  axios.get(`https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/${this.id}`)
    .then(response => {
      this.team = response.data
  }),
}
```

Here in this stage I have the team object.

What I want to do is to bring one more object who has related with team object in this page and carry to character component.

---

I want to call this URL `https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/character/{character_id}` and get the specific character object who belong to the team.

The character ID is in the `team.acf.acf_choose_character`.

I believe that what I am asking for has been understood.

Thanks in advance!

Below is the team object:

```json
"acf": {
  "acf_choose_character": [
    11
  ],
  "acf_choose pathways": [
    159,
    166,
    167
  ],
  "acf_team_final_score": ""
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a second `axios` call in the callback of the first one.

```js
mounted () {
  axios.get(`https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/${this.id}`)
    .then(response => {
      this.team = response.data
      axios.get(`https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/character/${this.team.acf.acf_choose_character[0]}`)
        .then(response2 => {
          this.character = response2.data
      }),
  }),
}
```

If you want to escape the callback hell, you can use [ES6 async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
async mounted () {
  const response = await axios.get(`https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/${this.id}`)
  this.team = response.data

  const response2 = await axios.get(`https://example.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/character/${this.team.acf.acf_choose_character[0]}`)
  this.character = response2.data
}
```

Comment: These snippets aren't equivalent. Promise pattern is supposed to help with callback hell.  The latter could be avoided in snippet 1 by chaining promises correctly and avoiding nested `then`.